# Callback function not defined even though it has been defined right before calling in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using for loop get all the data place in a div. I have following code in javascript so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callback(){
    $.getScript("/frontend/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js", function() {
      $('input').on('change', function(){
        var qty = $(this).attr('id');
        var price = $('#'+qty+'_price').attr('value');
        var subtotal = qty * price;
        $('#'+qty+'_total').html('&euro; '+subtotal);
      })
    });
  }

  function checkout(callback){
    let eventDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));
    var unique = eventDate.filter(function(itm, i, eventDate) {
        return i == eventDate.indexOf(itm);
    });
    let items = [];
    for (var n = 0; n < unique.length; n++){
        var eventId = unique[n];
        $.ajax({
            "url":"/get_my_product/"+ eventId,
            "type":"GET",
            "dataType":"json",
            "contentType":"application/json",
            success:function(response){
              let party = 'Party name';
              let html = "<tr class='product-row'><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>"+party+"</a></h5></td><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>"+response.date+"</a></h5></td><td value='"+response.price+"' id='"+n+"_price'>&euro; "+response.price+"</td><td><div class='input-group'><input class='vertical-quantity form-control dataqty'  id='"+n+"' type='number'><span class='input-group-btn-vertical'></span></div></td><td id='"+n+"_total'>&euro; "+response.price+"</td></tr>";
              $('#data').append(html);
            }
        })

    }
    callback && callback();
  }
  checkout();    
</script>
```

When I am trying to call the function after the loop completion it does not work. What is wrong here?

Comment: You're not passing an argument for the callback: `checkout()`  Did you mean to pass the `callback` function?:  `checkout(callback)`  (Note: Re-using variable names so close to each other, in this case `callback`, often leads to confusion.  Which appears to be what's happening here.)

Comment: asynchronous call 101.... that for loop will finish before the ajax calls come back. You order a bunch of packages from different places and you are trying to open them all up before any of them arrived.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but loading another jQuery instance with jQuery is most certainly wrong, or at least an indication of a logical problem.

Comment: @t.niese I did not know that it would create a problem. I am trying to reload js because I want to get the id of recently placed div with ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
function checkout(callback){
```

to

```
function checkout() {
```

I think the argument `callback` to the function `checkout` "shadows" the previously defined `callback` function. Then, when you call the function `checkout` you are passing nothing to the function, and `callback` will be `undefined`.

Or, in the last line, pass the function as an argument:

```
checkout(callback);
```

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane what do you mean with it does not work?  Is `callback` not called when you do that change or does the code within the `callback` function not work as expected?

Comment: Still only part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Makes no sense to add another version of jQuery to add events. You are not passing the callback to the method so it is always going to be undefined. And you are not waiting for the Ajax calls to complete before calling the callback.

```
// No reason for loading the JQuery version here
function addMyEvents() {
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    var qty = $(this).attr('id');
    var price = $('#' + qty + '_price').attr('value');
    var subtotal = qty * price;
    $('#' + qty + '_total').html('&euro; ' + subtotal);
  })
}

function checkout(callback) {
  // hold the ajax calls
  const myAjaxCalls = []
  let eventDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));
  var unique = eventDate.filter(function(itm, i, eventDate) {
    return i == eventDate.indexOf(itm);
  });
  let items = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < unique.length; n++) {
    var eventId = unique[n];
    // push the ajax calls to an array
    myAjaxCalls.push($.ajax({
      "url": "/get_my_product/" + eventId,
      "type": "GET",
      "dataType": "json",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      success: function(response) {
        let party = 'Party name';
        let html = "<tr class='product-row'><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>" + party + "</a></h5></td><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>" + response.date + "</a></h5></td><td value='" + response.price + "' id='" + n + "_price'>&euro; " + response.price + "</td><td><div class='input-group'><input class='vertical-quantity form-control dataqty'  id='" + n + "' type='number'><span class='input-group-btn-vertical'></span></div></td><td id='" + n + "_total'>&euro; " + response.price + "</td></tr>";
        $('#data').append(html);
      }
    }))

  }
  // if we have a callback
  if (callback) {
    // wait for all the ajax calls to be done
    $.when.apply($, myAjaxCalls).done(callback)
  }
}
// pass the function to the method.
checkout(addMyEvents);
```

Now the best part is you do not even need to worry about the callback to bind events. You can just use event delegation and it would work. This way whenever an input is added to the page, it will be picked up.

```
$(document).on('change', 'input', function() {
    var qty = $(this).attr('id');
    var price = $('#' + qty + '_price').attr('value');
    var subtotal = qty * price;
    $('#' + qty + '_total').html('&euro; ' + subtotal);
})

function checkout() {
  let eventDate = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("events"));
  var unique = eventDate.filter(function(itm, i, eventDate) {
    return i == eventDate.indexOf(itm);
  });
  let items = [];
  for (var n = 0; n < unique.length; n++) {
    var eventId = unique[n];
    $.ajax({
      "url": "/get_my_product/" + eventId,
      "type": "GET",
      "dataType": "json",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      success: function(response) {
        let party = 'Party name';
        let html = "<tr class='product-row'><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>" + party + "</a></h5></td><td class='product-col'><h5 class='product-title'><a>" + response.date + "</a></h5></td><td value='" + response.price + "' id='" + n + "_price'>&euro; " + response.price + "</td><td><div class='input-group'><input class='vertical-quantity form-control dataqty'  id='" + n + "' type='number'><span class='input-group-btn-vertical'></span></div></td><td id='" + n + "_total'>&euro; " + response.price + "</td></tr>";
        $('#data').append(html);
      }
    })
  }
}

checkout();
```